# What does a slash mean in an include statement?

Tags: c++, c

There is a following statement in the file:

```
#include "ssutil/DataBuffer.h"
```

Please let me know where to search this header file and how to interpret `ssutil/`?

Comment: That's not a backslash. That's a forward slash.

Comment: This statement is ill-formed. You need a `#` before the include, and the path needs to be surrounded by either `<` and `>` or two `"`. I fixed that for you now.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: Arguably this edit obscures the true level of confusion of the OP...

Answer (score 6):

It's a path component. `ssiutil` is a directory and `DataBuffer.h` is the actual header. The `/` is a path separation character used on Unix platforms like Mac OS X, Linux, the BSDs and others as well as Windows.

Comment: Don't forget Windows, DOS, etc. on which it's also used.

Comment: Ah alright, I'll update my answer. Didn't realize that was legal there. Admittingly don't do much development on those platforms in C or C++.

Answer (score 4):

That is a relative path and the preprocessor will look for the file in a directory called `ssiutil`. Precisely where that directory is depends on your compiler options. For example the MS compiler [searches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) like this:

> This form instructs the preprocessor to look for include files in the same directory of the file that contains the #include statement, and then in the directories of any files that include (#include) that file. The preprocessor then searches along the path specified by the /I compiler option, then along paths specified by the INCLUDE environment variable.

You may need to consult the documentation for your particular tools to learn how the search is done.